# How can I merge mobile and desktop bookmarks across Firefox Sync?

Tags: bookmarks, firefox-sync

I am using Firefox Sync to synchronise bookmarks between my (Ubuntu) desktop client and (Android) mobile client. The bookmarks are synched, but kept in separate folders, rather than together. On the desktop client I have:

- Bookmark A
- Mobile bookmarks

  - Bookmark B

On the mobile client I have:

- Bookmark B
- Desktop bookmarks

  - Bookmark A

How can I merge these folders? My goal is to have the following on both devices:

- Bookmark A
- Bookmark B

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there's no way to do quite that, but there's a workaround that gets something close.
On your desktop, press ctrl+Shift+B to show all browsers.  Then click on "Bookmark Menu" or "Bookmark Toolbar" and then copy and paste the bookmarks from that folder into "mobile bookmarks".  (You'll obviously want to use select all to speed this up.)  Sync the browsers and voila!

You'll still see the "Desktop bookmarks" everytime you go into bookmarks on firefox, but there will be no need to use it since it just contains an exact copy of your mobile bookmarks.